# Python pass Pointer to Delphi function

Tags: python, delphi, dll, ctypes

I have dll, that builded in Delphi, and I try to call function from it. Declaration of function looks like this:

```
function GetUid(UID:Pointer):Integer; stdcall;
```

This is equivalent to this C function signature:

```
 int GetUID(void *pointer);
```

Library handled using ctypes:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("mylib.dll")
```

But i stuck here:

```
res = lib.GetUid(?)
```

What I need to pass in this function?
Pointer is void *, but how make this rightly in python?

Comment: If I were you, I would use [`c_void_p`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_void_p).

Comment: You need to show the implementation of `GetUID`. The return value probably indicates success or otherwise. The `UID` parameter is probably meant to point to a `UID` data type declared by the caller. But how can we tell without the code?

Comment: @TLama Er, but what are you going to point it at? Anyway, it's more likely to by a `byref()`

Comment: Use `windll` instead of `cdll` to match the `stdcall` calling convention.

Comment: What does the DLL's documentation *say* you're supposed to pass to the function? Figure that out first, and *then* worry about how you represent a pointer to such a thing in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a high level language. You do not typically import a DLL from a C or Pascal native library and invoke it and pass variables from Python into a C or Pascal function taking a `void *` type raw pointer and then manipulate raw memory this way.

In short if you knew what you were doing you would know better than to try to do what you're doing here.

Let's suppose that your implementation is like this:

```
function GetUid(UID:Pointer):Integer; stdcall;
var
  P2:^Integer;
begin
  P2 := UID;
  P2^ := 0;
end;
```

Then, what you would want to do is pass in an address to a 32 bit integer. Of course my example above is absurd, because what would have made sense above is to just declare the parameter as an "int *pointer" (in C terms) rather than as a "void *pointer".

Whatever it is you're doing, the next thing that will likely happen is that you will corrupt your python interpreter's heap, and cause lots of fun crashes and errors.

A far more sensible approach is to read the Python documentation on writing C extensions that can manipulate native Python types (PyObject), and doing the same thing but in pascal, if you like.

p4d appears to be a workable way of writing extension DLLs in delphi:

```
    https://code.google.com/p/python4delphi/source/list
```

Comment: No. I disagree. Using ctypes is just fine and so much lighter than writing an extension in native code. If the asker would just tell us the expectation of the function the question would be trivial to answer.