# What does export mean as a Delphi procedure directive?

Tags: delphi, dll

I'm trying to crack the DLL referenced here: [How do I call a delphi function that takes and returns pointers of custom type from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925731/how-do-i-call-a-delphi-function-that-takes-and-returns-pointers-of-custom-type-f)

The DLL's signature is:

```
Procedure myFunc(Ptr:Pointer;Var Result:Pointer);Export;
```

I can't figure out what the "Export" at the end of signature means.

Looking through [the docs](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Procedure) it seems like "Export" is where a directive should go, but "Export" isn't one of the directives listed. In [this tutorial](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/dll_basics.htm) they show a procedure with "export" as a directive, but they don't explain it.

Comment: Downvoter, please help me by explaining what I could do to make the question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export` is a now defunct directive. It has no effect. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions):

> The directives near, far, and export refer to calling conventions in 16-bit Windows programming. They have no effect in Win32 and are maintained for backward compatibility only.

This `export` directive was used in 16 bit programs when exporting functions from a module.

FWIW, the link you gave in the question is not the product documentation but rather a third party website. I suggest you use the official documentation.